# onload calls function by sender

Tags: javascript

I have a drop-down list that allows users to select a school & the onchange event calls function ajaxFunction(sender) which retrieves the appropriate data.

```
<select name='school' id='school' onchange=ajaxFunction(this);>
    <option value = 'School1'> School1</option>
    <option value = 'School2' selected='yes'> School2</option>
    <option value = 'School3'> School3</option>
</select>
```

Because one of the schools in the drop-down list will be pre-selected, I need to call the ajaxFunction() at onload, but I have been unsuccessful so far. For me, the problem seems to be how to reassign the parameter "this" to the correct sender.

The following code is my latest (unsuccessful) attempt.
1. It DOES assign the correct value (school) to strUser.
2. It DOES call ajaxFunction() but ajaxFunction() says the sender is undefined.  :(

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("school");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    ajaxFunction(strUser);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Your select has id `school`? In the code above just have it as name

Comment: There is no id attribute for `select` element. Use this `<select name='school' id='school' onchange='ajaxFunction(this);'>`

Comment: Thanks, I have added the id, but still not working

Comment: @Crookers You missed out single quotes for onchange event. You can refer to my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

your select didn't have a id 
give id to it and try again

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery for this bro, the input don't have the id "school". If you want to use the attribute name use this:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var e = $("input[name=school]").val();
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    ajaxFunction(strUser);
};
</script>
```

Comment: Renan, your code says that strUser is undefined.  The original code DOES return the correct school - I just can't get it to call ajaxFunction() correctly

Answer (score 0):

```js
 window.onload = function () {
    var e = document.getElementById("school");
    ajaxFunction(e);
};

function ajaxFunction (e)
{
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(strUser);
}
```

```html
 <select name='school' id='school' onchange="ajaxFunction(this);">
    <option value = 'School1'> School1</option>
    <option value = 'School2' selected='yes'> School2</option>
    <option value = 'School3'> School3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Phani, ajaxFunction works fine without the quotes - I added them just in case.  The problem seems to be calling ajaxFunction() correctly from within window.onload

Comment: @Crookers You can find the working example above. In your select onchange, you are sending the select element as a reference to `ajaxFunction`. On window load, you get handle to select element and pass it to `ajaxFunction`.

Comment: I guess what you are saying is pass by reference (onchange) and pass by value (window onload). My problem is, how do I fix this - I know very little javascrript.

Comment: @Crookers In both cases, I am sending the object reference.

Comment: Phani, you ARE the man - works beautifully! Many thanks to you and all other respondents!